# php header won't redirect on one of my website

Tags: php, html, header

I've got two websites with the same content. One is with ".com" and the other one is ".nc".

I've got this php page:

```
<?php 
// si le mot de passe est posté 
if(isset($_POST["motpasse"])){ 
  // si la valeur du mot de passe est bien celle qu'il faut 
  if($_POST["motpasse"] == "pass") { 
    header ("Location: dernier.php"); 
    exit(); 
  }else {echo "Mauvais mot de passe";} 
} 
echo ('<p align="center"><font size=6pt>Veuillez saisir 
       votre mot de passe: <br></p></font>'); 
echo '<form name="motdepasse" method="post" 
       action="' . htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) . '">'; 
echo ('<p align="center"><input type=password name="motpasse" 
       size="5" style="height:60px; width:160px" value="" /></p>'); 
echo ('<p align="center"><input type="submit" 
       name="action onClick=(this.form)"  
       style="height:60px; width:160px"value="OK"></p>'); 
echo '</form>'; 
?>
```

Weirdly, the header function is working on the website ".com" but not on the website ".nc"

When I type the password, the header doesn't redirect me on the php page that I've put ("dernier"). Any idea why?

Comment: Domain suffix has nothing to do with this, perhaps each website runs on different server or with different configuration? The most common reason for header redirection to fail is sent content before calling header(), for example if you display some HTML or leave a whitespace before/after PHP tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is correct what JackBauer told you about the headers sent. another solution some nasty is this:

```
<?php 
// si le mot de passe est posté 
if(isset($_POST["motpasse"])){ 
// si la valeur du mot de passe est bien celle qu'il faut 
if($_POST["motpasse"] == "pass") { 
echo "<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=dernier.php">";
/*header ("Location: dernier.php"); */
exit(); 
}else {echo "Mauvais mot de passe";} 
} 
echo ('<p align="center"><font size=6pt>Veuillez saisir votre mot de passe: <br></p></font>'); 
echo '<form name="motdepasse" method="post" action="' . htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) . '">'; 
echo ('<p align="center"><input type=password name="motpasse" size="5" style="height:60px; width:160px" value="" /></p>'); 
echo ('<p align="center"><input type="submit" name="action onClick=(this.form)"  style="height:60px; width:160px"value="OK"></p>'); 
echo '</form>'; 
?>
```

But maybe the principal thing that is failing in your script is the action in your form. 
with firebug review your scaped html code in your client side. (what u r seeing in your browser {font code})

see ya!